# Laravel 5.5 querybuilder insert to table from array collection

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

How can I insert the collection into the database. I loop the values in my controller and when I do insert, It has some error in it `Array to string conversion (SQL: insert into`sms`(`user_id`,`msg`,`mobile_number`,`isSend`) values (1, SMS, {"phone":"+63 (971) 659-8143"}, 1))`. Can someone tell me what should I do about this? Thanks in advance

Controller Code

```
   if($request->smsn == 'on'){
            $events->smsnotify = 1;

            $numbers = \DB::table('users')
                        ->select('phone')
                        ->where('school_id', '=', $sid)
                        ->where('role', '=', $request->group_id)
                        ->get();

            $numbersArray = [];
            foreach($numbers as $number){
                $numbersArray[] = json_encode($number);
            }

                        // dd($numbersArray);
            $sms = DB::table('sms')->insert([
                'user_id' => $sid,
                'msg' => $request->name,
                'mobile_number' => $numbersArray,
                'isSend' => 1
            ]);

        }
```

when i `dd($numbersArray);`

```
array:9 [▼
  0 => "{"phone":"+63 (971) 659-8143"}"
  1 => "{"phone":"(0997) 212-7919"}"
  2 => "{"phone":"(0900) 117-9012"}"
  3 => "{"phone":"(0905) 470-0661"}"
  4 => "{"phone":"+63 (977) 194-0623"}"
  5 => "{"phone":"(0927) 448-8047"}"
  6 => "{"phone":"+63 (923) 889-3009"}"
  7 => "{"phone":"+63 (971) 215-1217"}"
  8 => "{"phone":"+63 (998) 452-5708"}"
]
```

I just want to insert the numbers with a comma separator in a single row of my table. How could I achieve that?

Comment: You want to add all numbers for single user?

Comment: i want to add all the numbers sir in a single column in the sms table sir.

Comment: for the same user right? and also comma saperated?

Comment: yes sir. Its like this `user_Id = 1, msg=random, mobile_no= 001,002,003, isSend=1`

Comment: use implode :     'mobile_number' => implode(',',$numbersArray),

Comment: the `mobile_number` column in my table sir is empty

Comment: check your data type in database, if you need to store big data take field as text

Comment: it is `varchar 191` sir. What should I do?

Comment: i should replace it to text?

Comment: it saves in this format sir `{"phone":"+63 (928) 206-5706"},{"phone":"(0817) 447-1492"},{"phone":"+63 (920) 203-3874"},{"phone":"+63 (978) 336-0763"},{"phone":"(0932) 215-2876"}` how could i remove the curly braces and the label? @YasinPatel

Comment: its laravel version 5.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way

```
 $numbers = \DB::table('users')
                    ->where('school_id', '=', $sid)
                    ->where('role', '=', $request->group_id)
                    ->pluck('phone')
                    ->toArray();
```

and you can directly `implode()` resulting array.

```
 $numbersArray = implode(',',$numbers);
```

You can skip `foreach` loop.
`$numbersArray` will give comma separated string to directly save in  column.

Answer (score 2):

```
$numbers = \DB::table('users')
    ->where('school_id', $sid)
    ->where('role', $request->group_id)
    ->pluck('phone')
    ->implode(',');


$sms = DB::table('sms')->insert([
    'user_id' => $sid,
    'msg' => $request->name,
    'mobile_number' => $numbers,
    'isSend' => 1
]);
```

You can `pluck` just the `phone` column from the table and then call `implode` on the Collection to implode the values by `,`.

[Laravel 5.8 Docs - Query Builder - Retrieving Results - Retrieving A List Of Column Values](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#retrieving-results) `pluck`

[Laravel 5.8 Docs - Collections - Available Methods - `implode`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-implode)

Comment: it returns an error sir `Array to string conversion (SQL: insert into `sms` (`user_id`, `school_id`, `msg`, `mobile_number`, `isSend`) values (2, 1, New Event asda, +63 (928) 206-5706, 1))`

Comment: then your query had no results

Comment: `implode` is returning a string, so the error isn't coming from there

Comment: how do i select multiple columns from implode sir? I want to get also the name?

Comment: added `toArray()` to what?

Comment: after pluck method

Comment: i just remove implode

Comment: why ... `pluck` returns a Collection, you can then call the `implode` method of the collection

Comment: i just copied the answer of @prashant sir and it worked for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202547/discussion-between-vince-and-lagbox).

Comment: i just want to ask questions.

Comment: ok sir. this is not about others answer now. how do i pluck multiple columns?

Comment: I have a documentation link for that method ... you are more than welcome to read it ... good luck with your project :)

Answer (score 1):

You adding a json format to your 3rd column.

before you insert . `json_encode` it first then later once you retrieved the data . use `json_decode` and you are free to your object notation coding eg. `$row->key`

In addition if you insert json value to a column. you do `JSON_VALUE` query as well

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-query-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: json_encode your created json array again to make it array of json (converted to string) for saving purposes.